# XCode: Application crashes without reason in main function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Most of my applications crashes with **SIGABRT** signal in **main function** when trying to run them on simulator. Crashes does not appear always, but somewhere in 50% of cases.
I have tried to use exception breakpoint but anyway it crashes in **main**. 
Strangely, but this crash can appear even at empty project.

So can someone help me with this issue?

I'm using XCode 4.6.2 with iOS 6.0.

Comment: Does this happen when you start a new project and just run that. Run a brand new project and see if it happens. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072135/how-to-track-down-cause-of-sigabrt

Comment: Yes, I just created new "Empty Application" and after 3rd launch it crashed.

Comment: Does this really happen in simulator only?

Comment: Looks like issue with XCode. Upgrade to Xcode 4.6.3(latest)

Comment: Did you try re-installing the tools?

Comment: @HermannKlecker, Yes, only simulator. And no, I didnt try re-installing the tools.

Comment: definitely do an upgrade to your XCode and Developer Tools and see if that helps

Comment: did u try nszombie?try enabling nszombie

Comment: @user1248568 Did you tried to run your application in instrument Zombies. This might will help you

Comment: Yes, it's look more like a memory allocation problem. Try enabling NSZombie (Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... / Run / Diagnostics). Are you using ARC or not?

Comment: I have also moved from Xcode 4.6.2 to 4.6.3 but didn't got any issue i think something wrong at you end. Use NSZombie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to XCode 4.6.3 helped me.