# Getting rid of SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, sigabrt

I keep trying to launch my app and it keeps "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" and sending me from the simulator back to this xcode screen:
![enter image description here][1]

I see that the problem is in the first thread but i dont know where at in my code or event paths this corresponds to.

here are the other parts of the 1st thread that contains the error:
[image]

The debugger says this:

> 2013-11-21 18:59:23.330 Bluetooth_RSSI_test[24377:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key set1m.'

Here is my code for that includes set1m(Note that aValue is a property(nonatomic, strong) of type NSNumber and has been synthesized):

```
in .h file
- (IBAction)set1m:(id)sender;

in .m file

- (IBAction)set1m:(id)sender
{
    aValue = RSSIvalue;
    self.RSSIat1m.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aValue];
}
```

Comment: i think you have to give a more detailed explanation

Comment: At the bottom of the call stack view there is a slider. Move it to the far right to expand your thread list. This will show you the calls between 11 and 0.

Comment: copy the exception from your log please... that will usually tell you a better place to start

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072135/how-to-track-down-cause-of-sigabrt/8072273#8072273. But right off the bat, the aValue is probably a primitive, try using a "%d" instead of "%@" when creating your string with format

Comment: i just tried using "%ld" and referred to aValue as (long)aValue, but i'll try that too

Comment: it says i cant bc %d is of type int and my argument is of type NSNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the outlet connected to IBAction.
PS: i can't comment thats why i put it as answer.

Comment: Yeah i tracked all the paths and everything seems to be in the right place.  I think it has to do more with the type im sending it meaning aValue

Comment: Ok i had the same issue, it was because the button action is not properly connected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @paqogomez i know but unfortunately my reputation is not sufficient to make a comment.

Comment: Then turn your post into a real answer.  Flesh it out and make it relevant. :)

Comment: Well Aravind I will up your reputation because you were right! I ended up deleting the button and outlet connections and remade them and it worked. Thanks!