# iOS - mysterious SIGABRT

Tags: xcode6

I'm getting a `SIGABRT` - any suggestions how I catch it?

The only clues I have so far are:

- the Exception breakpoint ([How to track down cause of SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072135/how-to-track-down-cause-of-sigabrt)) does not seem to be catching it
- it only crashes on the iPhone 4 device running iOS7 and not on the iPhone 4s simulator or the iPhone 6 device.

Here's my (pretty useless) stack trace:

[image]

UPDATE

A longer (but no less useless) stack trace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look in the console log. It will provide some info on the error which caused sigabrt. Also be sure to check your outlet and action connections. You may have deleted a outlet after you linked it up and that way xcode can't find that missing outlet you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT occurs when you accidentally/intentionally change connections of an outlet or an action. 
According to you, you deleted a connection by merely deleting it from the code but under the hood, it still exists. 
So, what you can  do is, click on the attribute which is giving the sigabrt and then click on the connections inspector on the right side of the Xcode.
If you see any stray connections, just delete it. This is how you actually delete a connection. 
Hope this helps.