# SIGABRT runtime error in xcode 6.1 (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sigabrt

The only change that have been made to the code from the initial have been made in **ViewControl.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    newMessage.hidden = true

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBOutlet weak var newMessage: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var newButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func newButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    newMessage.hidden = false
    }
}
```

yet I'm getting a `SIGABRT` error in **AppDelegate.swift** on

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Is this an **Xcode 6.1** error or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: If you are getting a SIGABRT, you should also be getting a related error message explaining the reason for the abort.  This is included in the crash report and syslog.  Please provide that message (and stack trace).

Comment: Is your `mewMessage` outlet connected to your storyboard/xib?

Answer (score 3):

There is most likely something fishy going on in you xib/storyboard. Check the connections to make sure all your `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` are connected correctly and that there aren't any connections left over from old, deleted or modified variables.

Other than that, it's hard to say without more information. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072135/how-to-track-down-cause-of-sigabrt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790993/sigabrt-with-no-error-message) for more help.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like Xcode doesn't break at the exception point - look into the error console for more information. See photo to see which window to select (it's the blue icon on the right).

[image]