# #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> casues 20 errors, no PFQueryTableViewController subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm currently writing iOS app using parse - i also have to mention that i'm beginner and started coding in objective-C only few days ago so i don't understand many things. I need PFQueryTableViewController - it doesn't show up in new>file>... so i checked webs and it seems i have to add:

`#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>` somewhere

Now most people talk about swift - you have add it in bridging file. I'm coding in objective-c and i have no idea where to put it.
Adding this line in AppDelegate causes 20 errors.

Can somebody help me?

PS:i have all frameworks i need - PFQueryTableViewController still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import this at the top of your .h file of the required controller

Comment: I did. Problem was my Xcode was outdated. Still even though now i can create PFQueryTableViewControler and no errors occur, i still have problem with passing from one UIViewController to tableview with PFTVC subclass. If i make "push" to PFTVC i get SIGABRT error.

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540170/sigabrt-runtime-error-in-xcode-6-1-swift